# Should I create a new question/answer out of a (good) partial answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, link-only-answers, self-answer

Regarding this answer:

*[What is the difference between '?', 'E', and 'T' for Java generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008241/what-is-the-difference-between-e-and-t-for-java-generics/28760323#28760323)*

Note the comments; Testo Testini writes: "...there should be one dedicated question with this answer."

Should I create a new, more specific question and answer it with this answer? If I did that, I guess I replace the content of the original answer with something like: "This answer has moved to here [link to new answer]"?

Comment: No, don't move or copy answers and don't vandalize existing posts. It the new (and "more specific") question would be a suitable sign post for that answer, then post that question and close it as a dupe of the original question.

Comment: You can safely assume this question already exists.  Searching for "[java] generics wildcard" produces 2764 hits.  Why the commenter doesn't use them is hard to guess, but people tend to not search very well in general.  This of course gives you no obligation to comply, just flag the comment as "no longer needed".